# Second derivative of a vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-fields

I wonder how to treat the "second derivative" of a vector field. For example, imagine we have a vector field $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we evaluate the derivative at two points $Df(a)$ and $Df(b)$ which are matrices! Now,

$$D[Df(a)Df(b)] = D^2f(a)Df(b)+Df(a)D^2f(b).$$

My question is, what is $D^2f(a)$? How can I treat this? I imagine is something identifiable with $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n \times n}$. In such a case, if I wish to compute the "matrix" norm of $D[Df(a)Df(b)]$ (as the sum of all entries) is this then the sum of all possible combinations of

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} f(a)  \ ?$$

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't know enough to give you a satisfactory answer, but what I do know, is that the second derivative would be a quadratic form. Agree with me, that since $\mathrm{d}f$ is a linear mapping, we wouldn't gain any information by defining the second derivative the normal way? (it would be $\mathrm{d}f$ itself).
For example, the Hessian form is the second derivative, in functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
If I find anything new, I'll come back here.

Answer (score 3):

As already answered by SAUVIK, if $f:E\longrightarrow F$,
$$Df(x)\in L(E,F)\text{  and  } Df:E\longrightarrow L(E,F).$$
So,
$$D^2 f:E\longrightarrow L(E,L(E,F)).$$
Now, the space $L(E,L(E,F))$ can be identified of the space of *bilinear* functions form $E$ to $F$ via the isomorphism
$$g\to\hat g,\qquad\hat g(x,y) = (g(x))(y).$$
The trick can be obviously extended to higher orders.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f'(x)$ denotes the derivative of $f$ at $x$, which is practically a linear transformation.

Now as you vary $x$ you can think of $f'$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^n})$, the set of all linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Now how do you give metric structure on L($\mathbb{R^n}$,$\mathbb{R^n}$)?

Define for $A \in L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^n})$: $|A|=\sup A(x)$ where $|x|\le 1$ (it's a compact set and linear maps are continuous so the supremum exists).

You can easily check that it's a metric on $L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^n})$.

So now of course you can talk about continuity and differentiability of $f':\mathbb{R^n} \to L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^n})$.

Comment: Add Latex, please!