# Second derivative of a multi-variable function $f:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

It is generally known that the first derivative of $f:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ at $x$ is a linear map $Df(\mathbf x)\in L(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n)$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{|\mathbf h|\to 0} \frac{||f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h)-f(\mathbf x)-Df(\mathbf x)h||}{\mathbf |h|} = 0,
$$
so technically $Df:\Bbb R^m\to L(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n)$. With the use of partial derivatives, we can express $Df$ w.r.t. the natural coordinates by
$$Df=
\begin{bmatrix}
        D_1f_1 & D_2f_1 & \dots & D_mf_1\\
        D_1f_2 & D_2f_2 & \dots & D_mf_2\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
        D_1f_n & D_2f_n &\dots & D_mf_n
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $f(\mathbf x)=(f_1(\mathbf x),\dots,f_n(\mathbf x))^T$, $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_m)$.

Now my question is

> What's $D^2f$?
>   What is a nice way to represent it?

Well, I know that we'd need $D^2f:\Bbb R^m \to L(\Bbb R^m,L(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n))$ but what are some nice ways to think about $L(\Bbb R^m,L(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n))$?

Intuitively I kind of see what $D^2f$ do, but I since my background in Differential Geometry and Multi-variable Calculus is quite limited, I've never come across any book that offer a nice symbolic way to work with $D^2f$. I suspect that it has something to do with tensor notation that I'm not familiar with.

Any help is very appreciated, especially if you can point me some nice books/articles treating the topic. My background is mostly in functional analysis so I'm not scared off by terms like Frechet Derivative and such, please feel free to use them.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295440/second-derivative-of-a-vector-field) is a related thing I found. The answers were good but did not address my question, which is the representation of $D^2f$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038218/what-is-the-second-derivative-part-i/2038258#2038258

Comment: Indeed, the second derivative at a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a bilinear map $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and then it becomes comfortable to use tensor notation to work with such objects. Such bilinear maps correspond bijectively to triply-indexed sequences $a_{ij}^k$ where $1 \leq i,j \leq m$ and $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Comment: More explicitly, if you fix a basis $v_1,\dots,v_m$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$, a basis $w_1,\dots,w_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and denote by $v^1,\dots,v^m$ the corresponding dual basis (and similarly for $w^1, \dots,w^m$) then any sequence defines a bilinear map $a_{ij}^k v^i \otimes v^j \otimes w_k$ (where an Einstein summation convention is used) and any such map is of this form.

Comment: @levap Excellent! I've also read your answer in the link you provided and it was very good. Thank you very much. I have 2 question though, if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Edit the question if it is appropriate or ask them here.

Comment: Firstly, I don't fully understand when you said that $D^2f_p$ can be interpreted in term of directional derivative. Could you please explain a little be more on why should it be the case? Lastly, do you have a name of any book that treat this matter the same way you just did?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I want you to write a short answer addressing my little first question so that I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: No problem, I'll do it soon.